# awk Compare 2 files, print match and difference based on Start Range And End Range:

Tags: unix, awk

I need to comapre two files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` and obtain matches, and non-matches, for this case 
I am looking to check Second field of `f2.txt` is lying between StartRange and EndRange of `f1.txt`,if yes then print first the second field of `f2.txt`, 
then print the entire line of `f1.txt`. And for no match found on `f1.txt` to state "Not Found" and then print `f2.txt` entire line.

f1.txt

```
Flag,StartRange,EndRange,Month
aa,1000,2000,cc,Jan-13
bb,2500,3000,cc,Feb-13
dd,5000,9000,cc,Mar-13
```

f2.txt

```
ss,1500
xx,500
gg,2800
yy,15000
```

Desired Output

```
ss,1500,aa,1000,2000,cc,Jan-13
xx,500,Not Found,Not Found,Not Found,Not Found
gg,2800,bb,2500,3000,cc,Feb-13
yy,15000,Not Found,Not Found,Not Found,Not Found
```

Comment: And what have you tried yet? And how that failed?

Comment: sorry no idea how to work on Ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { 
        FS="," # Field separator
        c=1    # counter
        while ((getline line < ARGV[1]) > 0) { 
            if (line !~ "Flag,StartRange,EndRange,Month") { # No need for header
                F[c]=line;                   # store line
                split(line,a,",")            # split line
                F2[c]=a[2] ; F3[c]=a[3]      # store the lines' range parts
                c++
            }
        }
      } 
FILENAME==ARGV[2] { 
    # Work on second file
    for (i in F) { # For every line scan the first file 
        # if within a range, step out
        if ($2>=F2[i] && $2<=F3[i]) {found=i ; break} 
        # else check next
        else {found=0}
    }  
    # if the above found anything print the line from second file
    # with the relavant line from the first
    if (found>0) { 
        print $0 "," F[found] 
    } 
    # otherwise the not found message
    else { 
        print $0 ",Not Found,Not Found,Not Found,Not Found" 
    } 
}' f1.txt f2.txt
```

Comment: thanks, while running this sytax , got the below error  gawk: cmd. line:8:                 F2[c]=a[2] ; F3[c]=a[3]      # store the lines
gawk: cmd. line:8:                                              ^ syntax error
range.sh: line 10: c++: command not found
range.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
range.sh: line 11: `            }'